# How to get input field name that value has changed [ Angular 6 ]

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular6

I tried reactive form valueChanges but valueChanges method doesn't return input field name which has changed.

I thought code like this. but I think this is not smart way. Because I have to compare every each input field. so I need more smart way.

```
  // get init view data from local storage
  this.localstorageService.getPlaceDetail().subscribe(data => {
    this.initPlaceDetail = data;
    // watch changed value 
    this.editPlaceForm.valueChanges.subscribe(chengedVal => {

      if (chengedVal['ja_name'] !== this.initPlaceDetail.languages.ja.name.text) {
        this.changedJA = true;
      }
      if (chengedVal['ja_romaji'] !== this.initPlaceDetail.languages.ja.name.romaji) {
        this.changedJA = true;
      }
      // ...... I have to check all input fields??
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding form controls from an array and something like this worked for me.  Just reference the item you need instead of expecting the valueChanges observable to pass it to you.

```
myFields.forEach(item => {
    const field = new FormControl("");
    field.setValue(item.value);
    field.valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
          console.log(item.name + " is now " + v);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to get changed control in form.

I shared for whom concerned.

Method to get list control changed values

```
private getChangedProperties(form): any[] {

    let changedProperties = [];

    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach((name) => {
      let currentControl = form.controls[name];

      if (currentControl.dirty)
        changedProperties.push({ name: name, value: currentControl.value });
    });

    return changedProperties;
  }
```

If you only want to get latest changed control you can use

```
var changedProps = this.getChangedProperties(this.ngForm.form);

var latestChanged = changedProps.reduce((acc, item) => {
if (this.changedProps.find(c => c.name == item.name && c.value == item.value) == undefined) {
       acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of listening to whole form changes you can listen to value changes event for each form control as shown in below code:

```
this.myForm.get('ja_name').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.formattedMessage = `My name is ${val}.`;
  });
```

Comment: thank you. but this way also have to check all fields right?

Comment: If I have 50 fields in a form, and when the form valueChanges I want to know what has changed - putting, ie. 50 valueChanges subscribers is not ideal ?